# Target directory structure for tar different than original directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, tar, archiving

Is there any way to set a different target directory structure than the orignial directory structure the tar archive was created from without creating it by hand?

For example, I have many files in a directory structure like this:

```
~/yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/*.*
```

Organized by when the file was received. I already create a tar archive *without* preserving the directory structure above for a whole day's worth of files (I have a small script that loops thru every minute of every hour and appends to a single tar archive). I would like to specify to tar to extract the archive to directory structure like this:

```
~/yyyymmdd
```

Seems simple enough as I could create the `yyyymmdd` directory by hand and just extract my archive into it, but I give this tar archive to a different system (which I have no control over) that relies on this tar archive being extracted to a `yyyymmdd` directory and the `yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/*.*` directory structure gives me performance gains because its organized. Also, I cannot change the original directory structure or waste system resources creating the desired target directory structure before creating the tar archive.

Is there a simple way extract a tar archive under a directory it was never in in the first place?

Comment: I don't. I apologize; I should have been more specific. The tar archive must be extracted just like this: `tar xf archive.tar` and produce a directory `yyyymmdd/` with all the files in it.  I will take a look at `--strip-components` and `transform`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have this structure

```
/home/yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/
├── dir1
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
├── dir2
│   └── file6
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

and you want this structure

```
/home/yyyymmdd/
├── dir1
│   ├── file4
│   └── file5
├── dir2
│   └── file6
├── file1
├── file2
└── file3
```

Create:

```
tar -cvf /tmp/archive.tar /home/yyyy/mm/dd/hh/mm/
```

Extract:

```
tar --strip-components=6 -C /home/yyyymmdd/ -xvf /tmp/archive.tar
```